# What's the difference between sensitivity and resolution of an SMU?

Tags: measurement, resolution, sensitivity

In Keithley's [Low Level Measurements Handbook, 7th ed](http://www.tek.com/sites/tek.com/files/media/document/resources/LowLevelHandbook_7Ed.pdf) the two terms are defined as:

> SENSITIVITY - the smallest *change* in the signal that can be
>   detected.
>
> RESOLUTION - the smallest *portion* of the signal that can
>   be observed.

which sounds exactly the same to me when looking at the system as a whole: resolution is limited by sensitivity and sensitivity is limited by resolution. The only case the two terms seem to have useful separate meaning is when addressing the sensitivity of the measuring component vs. the resolution of the sampling component.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Resolution in this context means the resolution of the *display*, which depends on the number of digits:

> A typical digital electrometer might have 5 1⁄2 digits, meaning five
>   whole digits (each with possible values between 0 and 9) plus a
>   leading half digit that can take on the values 0 or ±1. Thus, a 5
>   1⁄2-digit display can show 0  to 199,999, a total of 200,000 counts.
>   **The resolution of the display is the ratio of the smallest count to the maximum count (1/200,000 or 0.0005% for a  5 1⁄2-digit display)**. ([same source](http://www.tek.com/sites/tek.com/files/media/document/resources/LowLevelHandbook_7Ed.pdf))

Regarding sensitivity,

> The ultimate sensitivity of a measuring instrument depends on both its
>   resolution and the lowest measurement range. For example, the
>   sensitivity  of a 5 1⁄2-digit DMM with a 200mV measurement range is
>   1μV. ([same source](http://www.tek.com/sites/tek.com/files/media/document/resources/LowLevelHandbook_7Ed.pdf))

Comment: in this context , sensitivity is the smallest input with certainty above noise.

Answer (score 0):

> SENSITIVITY - the smallest change in the signal that can be detected.

- **Sensitivity** is defined a threshold, or a coefficient of some certain response for engineering applications

  - a capacitor has temperature **sensitivity** and *low sensitivity ceramics* might be sorted in bins for parts per million change in capacitance per degree Celsius [ppm/'C]

    - a negative value of -500 ppm/'C is defined as N500 and a positive value of +150 ppm/'C as P150 and if < +/-50 ppm or "zero" then it is binned as NP0. (NP "zero" is historically called NP "Oh")
  - in analog radios, **sensitivity** is defined as the threshold of an input signal with a certain minimal signal/noise ratio, SNR (defined certainty) or in digital radios, at a minimum defined minimal bit error rate, BER (defined certainty)
  - in an electro-optical sensor **sensitivity** is defined in terms of input parameters, output load, wavelength, response time and fixed at any other variable input
  - In electronic circuits, **sensitivity** can be computed as the partial derivative response to an input with a known transfer function, to derive a partial **sensitivity** factor or "S" factor
  - if simplified, the **sensitivity** can be a fixed ratio to power noise such as Power Supply Rejection Ratio, PSRR [dB] or as a curve PSRR(f) -dB vs f.
  - if complex, it may be a ratio or a set of curves such as transistors in response to input fixed or a sweep of current, voltage, temperature, or current gain, hFE.

This definition and context came from a Keithley ® instrument measurement handbook, such as their System Measurement Unit, SMU, that can measure **Sensitivity** as a set of curves and minimum threshold.

- in Medicine, **Sensitivity** can be defined as a measured response with a defined certainty (true positive)
- in human emotions, **Sensitivity** can be defined by an increased response to a low level input.

Some references in Wikipedia indicate when **Sensitivity** is a ratio, it should be called **Responsivity**, to applied Physics.

- However I was taught partial **Sensitivity** was the partial derivative of dx/dy of some function f(x,y), shown as \$\int_{y}^{x}\$.  This is very useful for computing **sensitivity** errors due to tolerance in any circuit or system.